# Regular Expression - Not any other words

Tags: regex

I have a regex to find if string have like this -> "#3232" substring.

```
/(#|\/)\d+$/
```

I want to find that if string doesn't have any other character except `/(#|\/)\d+$/`.

Here is an example

```
string s = "bla bla bla #3242 bla"; //no it has some extra characters 
                                    //except #3242

string s = "#3126"; // yes it's the right word, It doesn't 
                    // have any characters except #3126
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about anchoring the regex to the start and end of the string:

```
/^(#|\/)\d+$/
```

Comment: `^` matches the position before the first character of the string. In the example given, it would be the position right before the "b" in the first "blah".

Comment: @user1125457: Err, your `if` and `else` both write out the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/YwYzM/

Comment: @user1125457 Try not copy-pasting when you write code, your jsfiddle is wrong. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/bvgVU/

Comment: Why `(#|\/)`? Just use a character class

Comment: Oops. And that is exactly what you want to do. I thought you were trying to extract #3126 from the first string.

Comment: ok thanks all, I'm finding error with my fault, I have to sleep, I think.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew says, you should use the `^` operator to match the begining of the string. Also, when selecting single characters, the `[...]` operator is more readable. Try the following expression:

```
/^[#\/]\d+$/
```

Comment: You are right, I just want to add the names of those constructs: `[#\/]` is a character class and `(#|\/)` is an alternation (OR).